# TastyPie: ToManyField related resource

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a model which extends Django `User` model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='0')
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='contacts')
```

As you can see, there is a field `contacts`. By means of this field every user can have a list of contacts (like in Skype or social network).
But I want to use it in my tastypie resources. I have two resources:

```
class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'profile'
        excludes = ['id']
        include_resource_uri = False

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    userprofile = fields.ToOneField(UserProfileResource, 'userprofile', null=True, full=True)
    contacts = fields.ToManyField(UserProfileResource, 'contacts', related_name='contacts', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'userprofile', 'contacts']
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'patch']
        resource_name = 'user'
        detail_uri_name = 'username'
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

Everything is ok, but when I make a GET request, field contacts does not work well. I just can't understand, how to display list of other users in my contacts field in TastyPie resource. By the way, in Django admin page I can see the list of contacts and also I can edit it.

So, this realization of tastypie resource gives an ability to get a list of users who added a current user in own contacts list. But I need a list of contacts of current user. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since `contacts` is on the UserProfile model instead of the User model, the associated resource field should go on `UserProfileResource` instead of `UserResource`.

In any case, I'd recommend putting `contact` on a custom User object instead of a profile model; it'll simplify your code and save DB joins if you make everything related to User instead of related to a table that's related to User.

Comment: It does not work if I put `contacts` field to the `UserProfileResource` with error _maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object_.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest some decision using custom User object?

Comment: Oh, I missed that `contact` actually uses `UserProfileResource`, it should use `UserResource` since `contacts` is a m2m on the User model, not the UserProfile model.

Answer (score 0):

`contacts` is on the `UserProfile`, not in `User` and `contacts` is `User` type, not `UserProfile`:

```
contacts = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, 'userprofile__contacts', related_name='contacts', null=True, full=True)
```

If You really need `UserProfile`, try:

```
contacts = fields.ToManyField(UserProfileResource, 'userprofile__contacts__userprofile', related_name='contacts', null=True, full=True)
```

but I can not guarantee that it will work. It's only idea.